# Cutting a stack of paper into a shape with a router

Tags: drill-bits, drill

Apologies if this is not the right forum, but it seems to be a place full of people who would know how to do this.

I have a stack of a paper like material (papyrus, if it makes a difference) and I need to cut it into a particular intricate shape. It is very error prone and tedious to do this with a knife, so what I was thinking is that I could get a two metal or wooden forms corresponding to the shape, then put the stack of paper between, do a rough cut around the edges, then lock in place with a vice or something like that, and then using a hand drill with a suitable bit, run around the edge of the form to cut the paper to correspond to the required shape.

I'm not particularly handy, but I am looking for some advice. Particularly:

1. Is this a workable approach?
2. Is it safe, or am I going to lose a finger or eye in the process?
3. What sort of drill bit should I use?
4. Is there a better way to achieve the same end (without spending thousands of dollars on a bunch of expensive tools)?

At commenters request here is the shape (roughly 7" wide and 8.25" tall):
[image]

Comment: Can you upload a picture or sketch of how intricate the shape is?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Woodworking but as this is not a woodworking Question I've had to VTC.

Comment: The title refers to a router but the body of the Q and the tags refer to a drill. This is theoretically doable with a drill, but probably not the kind you're thinking as common power drills (both corded and cordless) aren't fast enough to make them efficient routers. It *might* still be doable, but ideally you want something capable of 10,000RPM or higher, with higher speed being more and more important the smaller the bit used.

Comment: Agree that this isn’t exactly the right place for this. Suggest you look at fret saws with spiral blades and use your sandwich template idea. Eg: https://www.leevalley.com/en-us/shop/tools/hand-tools/saws/fret/32920-spiral-fret-saw-blades

Comment: I would just find some company which has CNC vinyl/paper cutter (they usualy do signs and logos) and give it to them.

Comment: Considering it involves paper maybe [Arts & Crafts](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/) would be a better site for the question.

Comment: Maybe a bandsaw or scroll saw along with the "sandwich" approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this a workable approach?

I don't think so. I think a spinning bit is going to give you a fairly rough edge, and it also won't get into the inside corners that your shape has.

> Is it safe, or am I going to lose a finger or eye in the process?

I'd think so. As long as the stack of paper is clamped tightly between two pieces of plywood it should work about the same way wood does.

> What sort of drill bit should I use?

You should not use a drill bit. Drill bits are designed for drilling holes, so they mainly cut only at the end and in a direction parallel to the bit's axis. A small router, like a trim router, would be tool to use if you want to cut sideways, and you'd of course need a pattern bit or flush trim bit if you want to follow a pattern. But again, I don't think that'll give you the results you're hoping for.

> Is there a better way to achieve the same end (without spending thousands of dollars on a bunch of expensive tools)?

The right way to do this would be to use a press with a custom steel rule die. Having one of these made is probably pretty expensive, but there are videos on YouTube that demonstrate ways to make your own. A hand-cranked hydraulic press could work here; you can get one at a place like Harbor Freight for under $200 new.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

[I just came across this video,](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6MqDvdQX5oM) which starts with a guy using a bandsaw to cut a book into strips. So a bandsaw should work, (maybe even a jigsaw), as long as you're using something to compress the sheets together and keep them from sliding. You could use two sheets of plywood, and a whole bunch of clamps (you'd have to keep repositioning the clamps as you're cutting).

A laser cutter is another option. The machines for doing that cost thousands of dollars, but there are companies out there that will do it for you for a fee.